# 1004 error while creating and saving workbook in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have a function that gets a name for a new workbook, tries to open that workbook in the current folder and, if it can't do this, create a new workbook and save it in the current folder (and I am trying to save it with the name for the file, passed to the function). Looks like the workbook is created, as it opens (but with name "pasta11", which isn't what I expected) but it isn't saved anywhere.

```
Public Function SaveNewWorkbookToRelativePath(nameOfNewFile As String)
    Dim relativePath As String
    relativePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & nameOfNewFile
    On Error GoTo NoSheetHandler
    Workbooks.Open (relativePath)
    Exit Function
NoSheetHandler:
    Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename = relativePath, FileFormat = 52
End Function
```

The error is Runtime error 1004: application or object defined error.

Comment: This is not proper error handling. Check if the file exists or not and then decide wheter you want to save or you want to open the file. Also what is the value of `nameOfNewFile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Open or Create & Save a Workbook

**A Test**

```
Sub OpenMewTEST()
    OpenMew "Test1"
End Sub
```

**The Method (Sub)**

```
Sub OpenMew(ByVal BaseName As String)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Open Macro-Enabled Workbook"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const FILE_EXTENSION As String = ".xlsm" ' fixed
    
    Dim fName As String: fName = BaseName
    
    If StrComp(Right(fName, Len(FILE_EXTENSION)), FILE_EXTENSION, _
            vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        fName = fName & FILE_EXTENSION
    End If
       
    Dim wb As Workbook:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks(fName)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "A workbook named """ & fName & """ is already open.", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim fPath As String:
    fPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & fName
    
    Dim CheckName As String: CheckName = Dir(fPath)
    
    If Len(CheckName) = 0 Then
        
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' single worksheet
        
        Dim ErrNumber As Long, ErrDescription As String
    
        On Error Resume Next
            wb.SaveAs fPath, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled ' 52
            ErrNumber = Err.Number
            ErrDescription = Err.Description
        On Error GoTo ClearError
        
        If ErrNumber = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Workbook """ & fName & """ created and saved.", _
                vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
        Else
            If Not wb Is Nothing Then
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            End If
            MsgBox "Run-time error '" & ErrNumber & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
                & ErrDescription & vbLf & vbLf & "Could not save as """ _
                & fPath & """.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        End If
    
    Else
        
        Workbooks.Open fPath
        MsgBox "Workbook """ & fName & """ opened.", _
            vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    
    End If
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `NoSheetHandler:` is attempting to create a new workbook, and save it with just `relativePath`, no filename, no file extension. The error message is either because `relativePath` is not a valid filename by itself, or because that is the name of the file you currently have open, and you can't overwrite a file that is currently open.

Try to specify a workbook name and file extension in your error handler, such as `Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:= relativepath & "\NewWorkbook" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd_hhmmss") & ".xlsx"`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not clear why you chose to make it a function.
Even if we assume that you do need it as a function, you must give the function a type.
For example only: `Public Function Function1() As String.`

In my answer I will use a Sub.

I suggest the following code which is relatively short and lacks many necessary tests, but it is suitable if we assume that everything works well:

```
Sub SaveNewWorkbookToRelativePath(nameOfNewFile As String)
Dim relativePath As String: relativePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & nameOfNewFile & ".xlsm"
If Dir(relativePath) <> "" Then
   Workbooks.Open (relativePath)
Else
   Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:=relativePath, FileFormat:=52
End If
End Sub
```